# Why do errors differ when I interchange the order of the members of url patterns

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

> **Note:** I'm not requesting for a help to fix the errors, but to ask the reason why they differ by *interchanging the order of url patterns*.

The following is how my `urls.py` of my django application (`basic_app`) looks like:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('create/', views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

when I run the server and type in the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/create/`, it throws the following error:

```
ValueError at /basic_app/create/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/create/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'create'.
```

---

Interestingly when I interchanged the order of the 2nd and 3rd url patterns as follows:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from basic_app import views

app_name = 'basic_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('create/', views.SchoolCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

I got a different error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /basic_app/create/
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of SchoolCreateView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/basic_app/create/
Django Version: 3.2.4
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
Using ModelFormMixin (base class of SchoolCreateView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
```

I am new to django and curious about this event. Why doen't python let `create/` go to the next pattern to check since it did not fit the first pattern?

---

My `views.py` file looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import (
    View,
    TemplateView,
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from . import models


# Create your views here.
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'


class SchoolListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'schools'
    model = models.School


class SchoolDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    model = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_detail.html'


class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.School
```

Comment: Can you share the related views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have appended the `views.py` script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django aims to match url's top to bottom. If you thus visit `/basic_app/create/`, and the rule with the `SchoolDetailView` is first, it will fire that view, since `create/` matches with the regex `(?P<pk>[-\w+])/$`. Since the primary key of your object is likely an `AutoField`, it makes no sense to match a `create/` with `pk`, since we expect this to be an integer.

Another problem is that your `SchoolCreateView` is not configured correctly, you need to specify what fields will be used in the `CreateView`, so we can implement this with:

```
class SchoolCreateView(CreateView):
    model = models.School
    fields = '__all__'
```

We can refine the `re_path` of the detail view to only be triggered with an int, not with an arbitrary slug:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

or wiht a path converter:

```
path(r'<int:pk>/', views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
```